# Azimuthal equidistant projection

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox

I need map in "Azimuthal equidistant projection" for my HAM radio application. Can it be done in LeafletJS?

Here is description of the projection: http://flatearthdeception.com/maps-prove-the-flat-earth-deception/

Comment: The answer is "[yes](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html)". Please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this plugin (https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) and choose your desired CRS (Coordinate Reference System), I think it would be this one http://epsg.io/54032

Then simply copy the proj4js string into the plugin initialization code.

Comment: Does this also re-project the tiles, or do you need a WMTS serving tiles in the desired projection?

Comment: I don't remember :(